# How can I add two videos (side by side) in a quarto/revealjs presentation?

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I cannot find a way to put two videos side by side in quarto/revealjs.

```
---
title: "prueba"
format: revealjs
---

## Text

::: columns
::: {.column width="50%"}
Blah
:::

::: {.column width="50%"}
Bleh
:::
:::

## Images

::: columns
::: {.column width="50%"}
![cat](pexels-pixabay-45201.jpg)
:::

::: {.column width="50%"}
![cat](pexels-pixabay-45201.jpg)
:::
:::

## Videos

::: columns
::: {.column width="50%"}
<video autoplay loop><source src="full.mp4" type="video/mp4"</video>
:::

::: {.column width="50%"}
<video autoplay loop><source src="zoom.mp4" type="video/mp4"</video>
:::
:::
```

Is it possible?
Is the column environment the way to go?
I get a blank screen for the third slide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
---
title: "prueba"
format: revealjs
---

## Videos

::: columns
::: {.column width="50%"}

### First Video
{{< video https://youtu.be/wo9vZccmqwc width="100%" height="100%" >}}
:::

::: {.column width="50%"}
### Second Video
{{< video https://youtu.be/wo9vZccmqwc width="100%" height="100%" >}}
:::
:::
```